# Sed to Modfiy Hosts File

Tags: sed, awk, hosts

I have a text file, `modifyhostslist.txt`, which contains entries that correspond to entries found in my `hosts` file. Not every entry in my `hosts` file needs to be modified, only entries also found in `modifyhostslist.txt`.

The entries found in `modifyhostslist.txt` are to be commented out in the `hosts` file.

Sample line (entry) found in `modifyhostslist.txt`: `127.0.0.1 www.domain.com`

The following serves as the comment out sequence: `#%%#`

I've attempted to use `sed` to complete the task, but so far I've been unsuccessful. Here's my most recent stab at it:

```
while read line; do 
   sed -i 's/'"$line"'/#%%#'"$line"'/' /system/etc/hosts;
done < modifyhostslist.txt
```

In addition, the `#%%#` comments will be removed at specific intervals thereby returning the `hosts` file to its original condition. I suspect simply rearranging the command which is used to insert the comments can also be used to remove the comments in the `hosts` file?

It seems the `awk` command might work, but I'm unsure of how to use it as well.

Comment: How does the output from your current `sed` script differ from what you want?  In other words, what part of it was "unsuccessful"?

Comment: No changes are made to the `hosts` file when using the script even though it takes about 30 seconds for the command to complete. If I simply run `sed` command by itself (I specify single entry to modify; no `while read line`) it works great.

Comment: It works for me.  Is it possible that the spacing between the ip and the host name is different between the two files?  Maybe one is space-separated but the other tab-separated, etc?

Comment: Spacing between IP addresses and hostnames have been confirmed to be the same in both files. A single space is the separator (no tabs).

Comment: Please tell me if this is correct. While in directory that contains `modifyhostslist.txt`, I type the following at the command line:

`while read line; do sed -i 's/'"$line"'/#%%#'"$line"'/' /system/etc/hosts; done < modifyhostslist.txt`

The code is NOT contained in a separate script. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: That is the correct command. Are you running it as root or as a normal user?

Comment: As a test, run `grep -vFf modifyhostslist.txt hosts` (with appropriate paths added).  The output should be the lines of `hosts` _not_ contained in `modifyhostslist.txt`.  If any of the domains in `modifyhostslist.txt` appear in the output, that indicates that the lines don't really match.

Comment: @John1024, all hostnames are appearing in the output upon executing `grep -vFf modifyhostslist.txt hosts`. So, you are correct that lines are not matching. But, I have triple checked that `modifyhostslist.txt` and `hosts` file are formatted the same: each line is composed of the IP addresses, followed by a single space, followed by the hostname. I tested on another machine and I'm getting the same results... the command isn't working (same symptoms).

Comment: I'm running it as root. I even copied the hosts file to my home directory for testing purposes. Same results.

Comment: If they both "look" the same, is it possible that one file has DOS line-endings while the other has Unix line-endings?

Comment: My `hosts` file has additional commented out lines at the top, which are put there by my adblock program. When I remove those commented out lines, `while read line; do sed -i 's/'"$line"'/#%%#'"$line"'/' /system/etc/hosts; done < modifyhostslist.txt` WORKS! Any idea why?

Comment: The adblock program uses a single `#` to comment out lines.

Comment: Would it be possible to have `sed` command begin processing at line 23 in my `hosts` file? How would I do this? Beginning at line 23 would bypass adblock program comments.

Comment: If you want to try that, it is simple enough:  `sed -i '23,$ s/'"$line"'/#%%#'"$line"'/' /system/etc/hosts`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Despite specifying line number to begin processing at, the command doesn't work (same symptoms... `hosts` file remains unmodified).

Comment: How did you "remove those commented out lines"?  My guess is that that process corrected the invisible differences, quite possibly the line-endings, between the files.

Comment: I copied contents of `hosts` file into new text document. I then DELETED each of the (entire) commented out lines.

Comment: What I was looking for was whether the editor you used for the "new text document" was likely to fix DOS line-endings or not.  In any event, try: `sed -i 's/'"$(echo "$line" | tr -d '\r')"'/#%%#'"$line"'/'`

Comment: I don't thinking copying contents of `hosts` file and pasting into new text file fixed any DOS line-endings because if I kept the commented out lines in the newly created text document, the command still didn't work. Only AFTER removing the commented out lines in the new text document did it begin to work. I used Notepad++ in Windows to create/edit text files. Of course, I could be wrong. You know more about how this works than I do. Perhaps in my editing, I did remove some DOS line-endings.

Comment: @John1024, `sed -i 's/'"$(echo "$line" | tr -d '\r')"'/#%%#'"$line"'/'` works! THANK YOU! Is there some way to give you credit for posting the correct answer? This is my first time using the site so I'm unsure of how to give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the command:

```
while read line; do 
   sed -i 's/'"$line"'/#%%#'"$line"'/' /system/etc/hosts;
done < modifyhostslist.txt
```

As long as the lines in `modifyhostslist.txt` match the lines in `/system/etc/hosts`, that command really should work.

If the lines look identical to the eye but the command still does not work, the cause might be a mismatch between the (invisible) line-endings.  DOS/Windows files have two-character line-endings while Unix and Mac use one-character line-endings.  If this is the problem, the solution is to remove the offending characters.  Since `hosts` is a Unix system file, I expect that it has the correct line-endings and we thus need to remove the surplus `\r` characters from the `modifyhostslist.txt`  file.  This can be done as follows:

```
while read line; do 
   sed -i 's/'"$(echo "$line" | tr -d '\r')"'/#%%#'"$line"'/' /system/etc/hosts;
done < modifyhostslist.txt
```

Comment: To follow-up, I was able to convert DOS/Windows formatted text file `modifyhostslist.txt` to Unix and Mac formatted text file by using the following command: `tr -d '\15\32' < modifyhostslist.txt > unixmodifyhostlist.txt` (source: [link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux)). Further, my `hosts` file that I'm editing resides on my Android phone so I was able to use the app Jota+ to open the DOS/Windows formatted text file `modifyhostslist.txt` and "Save as..." the file in "LF (for Linux/Android)" formatted text.